# jQuery split problem

Tags: javascript, object, split

I have a script, which returns value as an object. It can return text or numbers, like `'hello, goodbye'` or `'500, 900'`.

When I try to use `split()` with this object, I catch an error:

```
TypeError: Object 'hello, goodbye' has no method 'split'
```

But I want to use split. What can I do?

Seems the only way to convert this object into a string, how to do that?

Comment: This has nothing whatever to do with jQuery or html.

Comment: Could you please post more of your code? What is this object? It cannot be just text, otherwise `.split()` would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

does `a = a+''; a.split('')` work? that should convert the object to string before split is called.

Comment: Using concatenation will call the object's `toString()` method, which by default returns *[object Object]*. The OP's object must use some other `toString` method, so it might be better to do that explicitly: `a.toString().split('<char to split on>')`.

Comment: To me this seems to be a workaround for the actual problem. But in order to give a proper answer we would need to know what the object is...